# Remove only new classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery's `.removeClass` can take no parameters to remove all classes, or a string with one or more space-separated class names, or a function that returns such a string. I'm wondering if there's a way to remove all but the classes specified in the original html (e.g., ones added by jQuery.) Something like

```
$('.myElement').removeClass(function() {return $(this).attr('class').split(' ').slice(1).join(' ')})
```

removes all but the first class, but that won't really work if the element has more than one classes in the html.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: I don't really see a practical solution to this answer, as the DOM provides no way to indicate whether or not it was added by javascript after page load, or if it was inherit to the HTML generated. Only a `mutation observer` may be able to detect it, but yet still, the logic and processing required behind it may become cumbersome depending on the amount of elements you must observe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to make a copy the original class attribute when the page is first loaded:

```
$('[class]').each(function() {
    $(this).data('orig-class', this.className);
});
```

Now, you can "reset" it:

```
$elem.attr('class', $elem.data('orig-class'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You must cache the original list of classes in a variable before commiting any changes, or you won't be able to recover it later.

[As far as I tested](http://jsfiddle.net/9tNPU/), all methods to add a new class (with jQuery or not) end up changing the `class` attribute, the `className` property, and the `classList`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get back the original attribute, so you would need to store it in data.

For example:

```
// On load, do this
myElement.data('originalclass', myElement.attr('class'));

// Later on, you can do this
myElement.attr('class', myElement.data('originalclass'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just made a quick plugin for this...

It replaces the original addClass function so it stores every class you add so when you wan't to remove them it knows what classes were added with `addClass`

This is the new `addClass function`

```
jQuery.fn._addClass = jQuery.fn.addClass; // Keep a copy of the addClass function

jQuery.fn.addClass = function( params ) {
    var _params = params.split(' '); // Split the classes into array
    var classes = this.data('classes') || []; // Get the current dynamic classes
    
    jQuery.each(_params, function( i, c ) {
        classes.push(c);
    }); // push the classes into the array
    
    this.data('classes', classes); // Re-set all classes
    this._addClass(params); // Add the class with the new addClass function
    return this;
};
```

And here is the remove dynamic classes function

```
jQuery.fn.remove_dynamic_classes = function() {
    var classes = this.data('classes')
    if( !classes ) return this;
    this.removeClass( classes.join(' ') );
    return this;
};
```

**Usage**:

```
$('#test').addClass('one two three');
$('#test').remove_dynamic_classes(); // This will remove classes 'one', 'two', 'three'
```

Here is a demo

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YFxRx/2/)

> This can probably be improved, but it's late and i may take a look at it tomorrow. You will have to inspect the element and play with the addClass function to see that it works.

Quick copy version

```
jQuery.fn._addClass=jQuery.fn.addClass;jQuery.fn.addClass=function(e){var t=e.split(" ");var n=this.data("classes")||[];jQuery.each(t,function(e,t){n.push(t)});this.data("classes",n);this._addClass(e);return this};jQuery.fn.remove_dynamic_classes=function(){var e=this.data("classes");if(!e)return this;this.removeClass(e.join(" "));return this}
```

Comment: @blenders answer is probably better, but it depends on how you wan't to use it. I'm sure someone will find some use of this.